# I can't pass data between two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a GridView in my form and I want when I click on a button to open another form and fill it with informations from the selected row in the GridView.

This is the code I tried in the form that contains the GridView:

```
private void barButtonItem13_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   DataRow getRow = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
   using (Collections_.ModifierCollection modifierCollection = new Collections_.ModifierCollection((string)getRow[1],(string)getRow[2]))
   {
      var result = modifierCollection.ShowDialog();
      if (result == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          // Just some code that I used
      }
   }
}
```

And this is the code I tried in that other form:

```
public ModifierCollection(String getKeyWordCollectionName, String getKeyWordEditeurName)
{
  collectionBox.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(getKeyWordCollectionName) ?
                                 "unknown" :
                                 getKeyWordCollectionName;
        editeurBox.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(getKeyWordEditeurName) ?
                              "unknown" :
                              getKeyWordEditeurName;
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

But it gives me an error in this line: `collectionBox.Text =  getKeyWordCollectionName;`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: possible duplicate: [what is a nullreferenceexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: most likely your `collectionBox` isn't created. try to move it after `InitializeComponent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `collectionBox` isn't created. Try to move it after `InitializeComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

use Value property in Cell of datagridviewRow

Comment: you cast a dataRow to String. but you are 1)Work with DatagridviewRow 2)Work with Value property in datagridviewRow 3)pass it between 2 form

Comment: please short your question . your question is very tall